# How can I create a fixed table header

Tags: php, html, css, pear

I have a table that is auto generated using php and pear html_table. The table has a th row across the top and they have a class of assetHeader. The table also has a th column down the left side with a class of timeHeaders. The table consists of 96 rows by an indeterminate number of columns. I am attempting to fix the top header columns and allow the user to scroll the table (this was they always see the header the cells belong to). I have tried the normal css tricks to fix the table headers in place like this:

```
.main .assetHeader
{
    /********************/
    position:fixed;
    display:inline-block;
    /*********************/
}
```

When I do this, the result is that all the headers are stacked on top of each other and only the last one is fixed to the left side of the table (and it is smaller than the actual column width). I then attempted a little jquery to add a class to the parent table row, like this:

```
 $('.assetHeader').parent('tr').addClass('headerRow');
```

The corresponding css is similar to the above, and this works but with improper formatting of the th cells (they are all displayed and fixed into place, but are all small and no longer line up with the columns they belong to). I have been working here and there on this feature for a couple of weeks now. I have tried many different approaches and have only included the two that seem most viable. Plus I cannot remember everything I've tried that has failed. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I dont think you can split a table like that.... tables are funny things. You may have to split the table header and table body into separate tables, and then use javasript the match the colum widths. I'm not positive, but i think that is the only way

Comment: I was worried about that. A small issue with that is the fact that all the column cells are linked to their column header and use this information to post selected cell and top header and side header information to a form that performs a query based on the selection. If I split the table up, wont I be breaking the ties to said information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it took a little time to get this right, but I believe the solution is solid. In any case, my testing hasn't broken anything. I ended up having to wrap my headers in nested div's and then fix the div in place and format with css. Here is the beginning of my table code.

```
echo "<div class='tableContainer'><div class='innerContainer'><form id='calendarForm' action='schedule.php' method='POST'>";
echo "<table border='0' width='100%'class='calendarTable'>";
echo "<tr><td width='1%'><img id='leftArrow' src='../images/buttons/arrow_left.ico'/></td><td width='2%'><input type='text' id='calDate' size='9' name='calDate'/></td><td width='1%'><img id='rightArrow' src='../images/buttons/arrow_right.ico'/></td>";
echo "<td align='center'><select name='deptSelect' class='deptSelect'><h1>" ?><?php
                        fill_dropdowns('DepartmentID','DepartmentName','Departments','x','DepartmentID',$dept);
                        ?><?php echo "</select></h1></td>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' id='roleID' value='$role'/></td>";
echo "<td align='right'></td><td><input type='hidden' id='picked' value='".$pickedDate."'/></td></tr>";
echo "</table></form></div>";
```

Then the tables are populated using php pear, and finally displayed like this:

```
    echo "<div id='head_container'>";
    echo $head->display();
    echo "</div>";
    echo $table->display();
```

and the css use to do the heavy work:

```
.tableContainer
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:-4px;

}
.innerContainer
{
    position:fixed;
    padding-top:5px;
    height:45px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#head_container
{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant approach, but it does the job for now.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the header like so - add a class too, if you wish
The thead tag is used as follows in **HTML**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Tried this suggestion just now. Using php and pear you don't get to throw in tags like <thead></thead>. It is done like this '$head =& $table->getHeader();' and then '$head->setHeaderContents(0, $i++, trim($val) );' inside a for loop. This can be done and does generate the thead tags, but then it breaks the links of the cell data.

Comment: Okay, I got the thead tags into the document and fixed the links to the cell data. Unfortunately this produces the same affect as my code. The row is fixed, all display, but the header columns are now smaller and no longer line up. Thank you for the suggestion, now I believe it will have to be combined with the suggestion from @iainvdw.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done via standard CSS, not reliably cross-browser anyway. You'll have to use custom markup (non-table elements) for that, or use a javascript plug-in such as http://www.fixedheadertable.com/.

Comment: I am attempting to make use of your suggestion, but its not working right. It re-formats the header, but does not fix the position. Now the header column is bigger than the table.

Comment: Okay, it is now fixed in place. Now the problem is that the headers had a column span of 2, and now they have no span. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?